# TypeError: data.comments is undefined

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, typeerror, use-effect

I'm fetching two things. An item by id and then the item comments by item id. I when npm start I get

```
TypeError: data.comments is undefined
```

But if I comment out

```
<Comment data={itemComments} />
```

And then run npm start, the item data loads and if I uncomment the comment tag after the item data has already loaded comments shows until I refresh or reload again, it's only when I try to load them simultaneously I get the error.

**Item.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Comment from "./Comment";
import axios from "axios";
const Item = () => {
  const itemId = "6019afbce548e33e7c2f4e56";
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [itemComments, setItemComments] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    const item = `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items/${itemId}`;
    const itemComments = `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items/${itemId}/comments`;

    const getItem = axios.get(item);
    const getItemComments = axios.get(itemComments);
    axios.all([getItem, getItemComments]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const allItemData = allData[0].data;
        const allItemCommentsData = allData[1].data;

        setItem(allItemData);
        setItemComments(allItemCommentsData);
      })
    );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Price</p>
          <p>${item.price}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Offers & Comments</h3>
          <Comment data={itemComments} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

**ItemComments.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Message = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      {data &&
        data.comments.map((comment, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <div>
              <div>
                <p>{comment.comment}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Message;
```

Comment: can you share `console.log(allItemCommentsData)` inside axios ?

Comment: Probably you are trying to render something empty.. Did you try? {itemComments?.comments && <Comment data={itemComments} />}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After first render react try to access `comments` inside `itemComments` when its just an empty array, and you just check if its not `undefined` in your children component:

```
{data && data.comments.map((comment, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <div>
              <div>
                <p>{comment.comment}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
```

so change your initial state to this:

```
const [itemComments, setItemComments] = useState({comments:[]});
```

Comment: This fixed it, could you explain the difference between what I have and this?

Comment: @Erykj97 check answer again.

Answer (score 0):

name your comment state by its initial name like this "useState({comments:[]})" and make sure that data.comment is not empty and also try to make fetch data asynchronously and let me know the result, please

```
 const fetchData = async () => {
    const item = `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items/${itemId}`;
    const itemComments = `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items/${itemId}/comments`;

    const getItem = await axios.get(item);
    const getItemComments = await axios.get(itemComments);
    const allData=await axios.all([getItem, getItemComments])
    const allItemData= await axios.spread((...allData) => allData[0].data)
    const allItemCommentsData= await axios.spread((...allData) => allData[1].data)
    
    setItem(allItemData);
    setItemComments(allItemCommentsData);
  };
```